# $f^{*}$ is surjective if and only if $f$ is injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I’m having a hard time understanding this proof and I hope someone could help me.

> **Theorem:** Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ a map. Think of this map as inducing the map $f^{*}: \mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$. Then, $f^{*}$ is surjective if and only if $f$ is injective.

The $\Longleftarrow$ part I already prove it:

> *Proof:* $\Longleftarrow.$ Suppose $f$ is injective. Hence, we know that $E = f^{*}(f_{*}(E))$ for all subsets $E \subseteq A$. Let $S$ be a subset of $A$. Then $S \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. We define the set $X_0$ as $X_0 = f_{*}(S)$. Observe that $X_0 \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Hence $f^{*}(X_0) = f^{*}(f_{*}(S)) = S$. Therefore $f^{*}$ is surjective. $\square$

For the $\implies$ part, I don’t know what to do.

**My attempts:**

1. I tried to prove the contrapositive, so if $f$ is not injective, then $f^{*}$ is not surjective. Suppose that $f$ is not injective. Then there exists some $a,b \in A$ such that $a \neq b$ and $f(a) = f(b)$. But I don’t know what to do next.
2. I tried a direct proof: Suppose that $f^{*}$ is surjective. Hence for all $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, there exists some $Y \in \mathcal{P}(B)$, such that $f^{*}(Y)=X$. Since $A \subseteq A$, we have that $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. So there exists some $Y_0 \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ such that $f^{*}(Y_0) = A$. But, again, I don’t know where to go next.

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly is $f^ *$ and $f_*$ in this context?

Comment: And what exactly is $\mathcal P$?

Comment: @MushuNrek here we think of the map $f$ as inducing the map $f_{*}$ and $f^{*}$. This means that for $X \subseteq A$ we have that $f_{*}(X)=\{f(x)|x\in X\}$. The same goes for the map $f^{*}$. Hope it is more clear now. (Think of the definitions of image and inverse image)

Comment: @Arthur Let $S$ be a set. By definition, $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is the set of all the subsets of $S$. We call $\mathcal{P}(S)$ the *power set* of $S$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x,y$ are two distinct elements of $A$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Since $f^*$ is surjective there is a subset $E\subseteq B$ such that $\{x\}=f^*(E)$. Now, we have $x\in\{x\}=f^*(E)$ and hence $f(x)\in E$. Thus:

$f(y)=f(x)\in E$

But this means $y\in f^*(E)=\{x\}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Oh now I see! Thank you so much! It is much clear now!

Answer (score 1):

Following on from your attempt 1.  You need to show that $\{a\}$ is not in the image of $f^*$.  Specifically, show that if $a\in f^*(X)$ then $\{a\}\neq f^*(X)$.

Comment: That is one of the *hints* given in the problem, but I’m having trouble understanding why showing that if $a \in f^{*}(X)$ then $\{a\} \neq f^{*}(X)$ will show the result

Comment: $$a\in f^*(X)\implies f(a)\in X\implies f(b)\in X \implies b\in f^*(X)$$